# Using Laravel is it possible to bypass the need for remember_token using an external user database

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

With a recent update of Laravel they require a remember_token, and also updated_at.

When logging in and out I get:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'remember_token' in 'field list' (SQL: update `account` set `remember_token` = s8XPDCdNdJnjbLj7MlDRO1Cy5owwjxdfW1rYVhd6QpePIltqPkavr9l3KUbd, `updated_at` = 2014-07-30 14:09:37 where `id` = 5)
```

I am using an external user database which I don't want to create these extra fields on, as it is used also on a game server which I don't want to mess with..

Is there a way to bypass the need for both of these columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure using Laravel's built in Auth system (Guard) makes you use UserInterface which, in turn, makes you define these. However, you could just fake it by having these methods but making them return useless information.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        // just anything that's not actually on the model
        return 'trash_attribute';
    }

    /**
     * Fake attribute setter so that Guard doesn't complain about
     * a property not existing that it tries to set.
     *
     * Does nothing, obviously.
     */
    public function setTrashAttributeAttribute($value)
    {
    }
}
```

That might just do what you want - basically override these functions to not work correctly, which means that 1) you don't need to mess with your DB and 2) when the functionality doesn't work it's okay because you're not using it anyway.

---

And as @neeraj says, for the `created_at` thing, just do `$timestamps = false` and hope for the best. Updated model above to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed this error but it seems like it's now trying to update the ID field when I logout? Error is: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'gsQOWmsGs9wADnE7bePci0Ap6ZPhwrgymH8xys3zLa7CcF3wBO6ZTYg7TQVn' for column 'id' at row 1 (SQL: update `account` set `id` = gsQOWmsGs9wADnE7bePci0Ap6ZPhwrgymH8xys3zLa7CcF3wBO6ZTYg7TQVn where `id` = 5)

Comment: Hmm that's surprising that it's trying to set that directly - it *should8 be using the `setRememberToken` method in my opinion. Very naughty. I have an idea which I'll add to the answer in a bit (basically create a fake attribute with the setWhateverAttribute function).

Comment: That's because the `logout` method, as well as many others in the `Illuminate / Auth / Guard` class, refreshes the user `remember_token`. You shouldn't have blindly updated.

Comment: @Ben I still feel like Laravel should be using the methods it makes you actually implement (setRememberToken) rather than going over your head, but hey. In fact I don;t see the point in `getRememberTokenName` at all but hey, no-one said Laravel was perfect (okay a bunch of people did but that's a different story).

Comment: @user2087032 I have updated the code sample to basically silently ignore Laravel's attempts to set the remember token field on the User at any stage in the process. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Ben I have filed a [bug report](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5277) on this as it appears to be erroneous (or at least can be done another way that would have worked with my original code rather than involving the hack-on-a-hack). I don't expect much on this as it would be super low-priority, and Taylor can sometimes be rather dismissive of things that aren't seen as being really constructive/helpful in terms of progressing the framework.

Comment: @user2087032 FYI my bug report was noticed and so I put a [PR through](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/5287#event-148043418) and it's now been merged. So now, theoretically, my original answer should work, as Laravel won't be trying to go behind your back any longer.

Comment: I'm using the code that's currently there and it's working for me now. Thanks a lot for your help Alex!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. This code should allow you to avoid having to use the 'remember_token' in your users table

```
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return null; // will not support
}

/**
 * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return void
 */
public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    // will not support
}

/**
 * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return null; // will not support
}

public function setAttribute($key, $value)
{
    $isRememberTokenAttribute = $key == $this->getRememberTokenName();

    if( ! $isRememberTokenAttribute )
    {
        parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing below interface from your modal

```
RemindableInterface
```

For created_at and updated_at, you can write the below line in modal:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

For example, if your modal name is Admin then code should look like

```
class Admin extends Eloquent implements UserInterface
{

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `RemindableInterface` is not the cause of the `remember_token` column requirement, so just removing this interface will not work. The `remember_token` filed is used in `UserInterface`, and this (I think) is required to use Laravel's own auth system.